# Subject of infinitive clause with "expected"

Tags: complementation, licensing, cleft-constructions

*You are expected to be well informed.*

Is it possible to rewrite the above sentence in this way:

*It is expected from you to be well informed.*

Answer (score 1):

"Of" should replace "from",

We say "expect soemthing from somebody".

Comment: +1. Yes.**From** refers to that which can come forth  "I expected a better performance from him on that song" and **of** refers that which inheres, a state, condition, or quality:  "It was expected of us to be prepared for almost anything."

Comment: @TRomano Not arguing with you, but the infinitive feels really awkward in the cleft sentence.

Comment: @StoneyB: As you know, things have appeared awkward to me, or even strange, which others have found perfectly acceptable. I think this time that may be happening to you. To me this cleft with the infinitive seems a normal Germanic construction, if a little dated, perhaps; people nowadays tend to say "We were expected to be..." rather than "It was expected of us to be..."  The "of us" raises the stakes.